# PHPStan, exclude all and specify files to check

Tags: phpstan

Im trying to setup PHPStan on a older, bigger, codebase. How could i exclude everything and than maybe by config define what to analyse.

I have thought about using a separate folder for it, but that would mean constantly moving files which might lead to breaking of the code. So i am hoping to exclude everything and then adding files to the analysers per file.

At this moment the only solution i was able to find is defining a script in `composer.json`

  `` "scripts": {
    "phpstan": "./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --memory-limit=1G --no-progress --level 1 `cat phpstan_analyse_files`"
  } ``

And keeping a list of files to analyise in the file `phpstan_analyse_files`

Comment: You can make phpstan analyze individual files. `php phpstan.phar analyse src/index.php src/blog.php` so if you're using git, you can probably make a hood that triggers phpstan(or whatever tool you use phpstan with)

Comment: Mauran, thats the only option i found as well, defining as params, but thats not a very sustainable solution. So what im thinking now is using php phpstan.phar analyse `cat files_to_analyse`. If you have any other solutions im all ears

Comment: Actually i totally forgot. I don't think its a good idea to only analyse specific files and not the whole project. phpstan would probably say "Class not specified" when using classes thats not defined in new files etc.

Comment: @MauranMuthiah This is not true. What directories do you analyze does not affect how classes are found. That's a concern of the autoloader and is unrelated.

Comment: @Michal-sk Basically you're doing it right. Combining multiple simpler tools (`phpstan`, `cat`) to achieve a complex outcome is the way to go ;)

Comment: @OndřejMirtes , guess i couldn't get a more confirming answer than this ;) Thanks for all your work and time!

Comment: You can also create a baseline https://phpstan.org/user-guide/baseline which ignores all current issues found. So any new code you add to your older codebase will be checked. This will allow you to scan your entire project.

Answer (score 25):

The best way to do what you need is `excludePaths` section as of PHPStan 1.0:

```yaml
# phpstan.neon
parameters:
    excludePaths:
        - 'old-code/OldClass.php'
        - 'another-old-code/*'
```

See [docs](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/ignoring-errors#excluding-whole-files) or this [real project `phpstan.neon` setup](https://github.com/TomasVotruba/shopsys-spryker-and-sylius-analysis/blob/f1c2a26625c686034a10095ec66a60fd75b718f9/config/phpstan/shopsys.neon#L34-L41) for inspiration.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i think the best way is to just stick with what we got now regarding keep an file with what we do want to scan and cat that into the call.

Comment: Note: Using configuration file /var/www/phpstan.neon.
Configuration parameters excludes_analyse and excludePaths cannot be used at the same time.

Parameter `excludes_analyse` has been deprecated so use `excludePaths` only from now on.

Comment: @thejimbirch Thank you, I've updatd the answer to match new PHPStan config!